# Loading additional model data using read method in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in edit method that allows a user to edit their account details. It uses both the User and Profile models and should be updating both.

I have used the contain in the find to load in the Profile information and also called the Profile model using the $uses var at the top of the controller.

But how do I load in both models into the read method?

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array( 
                    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
                    'contain'=>'Profile'
                ));

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
        {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'edit'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Whoops! Something went wrong... try again?'));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $user['User']['id']);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the docs `read()` only brings the expected fields. If you want to read related Models use `find` instead.

Instead of this:

```
$this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $user['User']['id']);
```

use this:

```
$this->request->data = $this->User->find('all', 
       array(
         'conditions' => array('User.id' => $user['User']['id']), 
         'contain'    => 'Profile'
       )
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1018/find

Answer (score 0):

You can call the contain() method just before read().

```
$this->User->contain(array('Profile'));
$this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $user['User']['id']);
```

Please note that the effect of this call to contain() will not persist after any call to read() of find().

Answer (score 0):

Just did this: `$this->request->data = $user;`

And seems to work fine. Can anyone see any issues with doing it this way?